# Odoo POS - Open a session

Tags: odoo, odoo-8

I wanna try Odoo POS, when I open a session, and loading stops in this part as picture shows, can someone help me please, thank you :)
[image]

**Console message**

```
2016-04-04 08:35:39,960 7157 WARNING test2 openerp.models: area.area.read() with unknown field 'users_ids'
2016-04-04 08:35:39,960 7157 WARNING test2 openerp.models: area.area.read() with unknown field 'capacities'
2016-04-04 08:35:39,960 7157 WARNING test2 openerp.models: area.area.read() with unknown field 'available_capacities'    
2016-04-04 08:35:39,960 7157 WARNING test2 openerp.models: area.area.read() with unknown field 'area_id'
```

Comment: can you put your terminal error or JavaScript error in this question? so i will better understand.

Comment: Hello Patel thanks for ur comment, i got this warning on my console:     2016-04-04 08:35:39,960 7157 WARNING test2 openerp.models: area.area.read() with unknown field 'users_ids'
2016-04-04 08:35:39,960 7157 WARNING test2 openerp.models: area.area.read() with unknown field 'capacities'
2016-04-04 08:35:39,960 7157 WARNING test2 openerp.models: area.area.read() with unknown field 'available_capacities'
2016-04-04 08:35:39,960 7157 WARNING test2 openerp.models: area.area.read() with unknown field 'area_id'

Comment: you working with your customize module because i can not find 'area_id'  filed in odoo 8 and odoo 9..

Comment: yes I'm sorry i didnt notice that, by the way i got warning when I choose demo data, now when i make database without demo, i got no warning but  loading still stuck, on my console just keep this:                                                       2016-04-04 12:52:58,582 13923 INFO test_without_data werkzeug: 127.0.0.1 - - [04/Apr/2016 12:52:58] "POST /web/dataset/search_read HTTP/1.1" 200 -
2016-04-04 12:53:08,152 13923 INFO test_without_data werkzeug: 127.0.0.1 - - [04/Apr/2016 12:53:08] "POST /longpolling/poll HTTP/1.1" 200 -

Comment: Since you're using a custom module we'd need some sample code aswell